# How to set up Typescript with a React state with an Object?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am new to TypeScript. I understand how to set up an `interface` for some types (I guess). But can't seem to grasp how the same would work with an `Object` type?

```
interface MyProps {
    defaultgreeting: 'Hello'
}

interface MyState {
    greeting: string
}

class MyApp extends Component<MyProps, MyState> {
    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
        this.state: {
            greeting: this.props.defaultgreeting
        }
    }
}
```

How would I have to set this up for the following state (which requires an `Object`)?:

```
this.state: {
    greeting: this.props.defaultgreeting,
    users: {
        name: 'John Doe',
        age: 25
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You have a couple options.

You can define the `Users` object within the `MyState` interface like so:

```
interface MyState {
    greeting: string;
    users: {
       name: string;
       age: number;
    }
}
```

Or, you can define the `Users` object somewhere else and assign it's type to the `users` attribute like this:

```
interface User {
   name: string;
   age: number;
}

interface MyState {
   greeting: string;
   users: User;
}
```

I usually prefer the second option because it lets you type the object by itself like:

```
const users: User = {
   name: "John Doe",
   age: 25
}
```

You can not do that with the first option. Although you can implicitly assign it:

```
interface MyState {
    greeting: string;
    users: {
       name: string;
       age: number;
    }
}

const users = {
   name: "John Doe",
   age: 25
}

const state: MyState = {
   greeting: "Hello",
   users
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
interface MyState {
    greeting: string;
    users: {
        name: string;
        age: number;
    }
}
```